# get jsonArray from table

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I  have a table and need to  build json array.  I need value from 1 and 4 column of table.

**HTML**

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="development_mapping">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Visual Feature</th>
                                        <th>Step</th>
                                        <th>Output</th>
                                        <th>Data Feature</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>                      
                                <tr><td>color</td> 
                                        <td><select id="sss"><option data-id="528092be144b4fbf65893404" selected="selected">first-step</option><option data-id="52809373144b4fbf6589340c">kmeans</option></select></td>
                                        <td><select id="ooo"><option data-id="output" selected="selected">output</option></select></td>
                                        <td><input id="value1" class="feature-execution"value="id"></td></tr></tbody>                                        
                            </table>
```

Here is my solution, a function to made an json array from table

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var jsonArray = {};

$('#development_mapping').find('tr').each(function () {
    var name = $(this).find('td:first').text(); 

    jsonArray[name] = {

          variable : $(this).find('td:eq(3)').text()

    }; 
});
```

I have done, but not understand, why I get `" "` from value of 4 column. I mean, why *variable* in variable  is always  getting `" "`

This is my [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/toshkaexe/7q3KP/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector: `$('#development_mapping').find('tr')` is selecting *all* `<tr>` tags in the table.  Even the one in the `<thead>`!  The `<thead>` doesn't have `<td>` tags, so that's where the `" "` is coming from.

Try this:

```
$('#development_mapping').find('tbody tr').each(function () {
    var name = $(this).find('td:first').text(); 

    jsonArray[name] = {

          variable : $(this).find('td:eq(3)').text()

    }; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `.text()` but there is no actual text in your 3rd `td` tag.

try this maybe?

```
variable : $(this).find('td:eq(3) input').val()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems with your code.

1. Remove the surrounding `<tr>` in your table head definition.
2. Use this to access input value

   `variable: $(this).find('td:eq(3) > input').first().val()`

`$.find()` will return a collection and you'll need to get the first object of the collection for further use. Plus, you'll need to search for input inside the cell, not the cell itself.

Here is the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/toshkaexe/7q3KP/